# Roblox Lua Values not changing

Tags: lua, roblox

I've added multiple different NumberValues and BoolValues, yet when i try to change the values with something like this for example:

```
local i = 1
for i == 1
    game.Workspace.Time.Value = 0
    wait(120)
    game.Workspace.Time.Value + 0.5
end
```

and the NumberValue in the workspace won't change

Comment: If lua works like every other language, `game.Workspace.Time.Value + 0.5` doesn't overwrite the old value of `Value`. It adds the numbers, then discards the result. You probably need. `+=`.

Comment: Also, you're resetting it back to 0 at the start of each loop, so even if that did change `Value`, it would immediately get changed back to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Random side note: game.Workspace is deprecated, use 'workspace' instead.

Also, the syntax behind it is all wrong, which is an honest mistake. It should look like this:

```
-- Assuming "Time" is a 'NumberValue' under workspace
-- Assuming this script is in workspace

local i = 1
while (i == 1) do
    local time = workspace:FindFirstChild("Time") -- Usage of the 'FindFirstChild' method
    time.Value = time.Value + 0.5
    wait(120)
end
```

However, this itself is bad practice because this will yield whatever thread you're running this in, and for this I suggest coroutines!

```
local function addTime()
    local varContainer = workspace:GetFirstChild("Time")
    repeat
        varContainer.Value = varContainer.Value + 0.5
        wait(120)
    until false
end

local newThread = coroutine.create(addTime) -- Create the new coroutine

coroutine.resume(newThread) -- Run it forever in another running thread
```

Comment: There's no reason to bring coroutines into this

Comment: Yeah I don't know if its the coroutines but when I try checking the time while testing my studio crashes

Comment: I simply gave coroutines as a different avenue, assuming that this would be a driver script, and more contents were going to follow this block.